# How to enable the NoDelay parameter for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tcpip, configuration-manager

We have a recommendation from performance audit to "enable the "NoDelay" parameter on our database".
I searched through Microsoft documentation and found that this parameter is configurable with SQL Configuration manager :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-protocols-tab

[image]

However, there is no "no delay" option configurable :

[image]

I also search through database advanced options and Windows Registry without success. 
Google shows some pictures with the option :

[image]

Any idea how to enable this ?

We are running SQL 2008 R2

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012
>   08:36:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: But what do you expect from enabling it? There is already No Delay, so what you'd like to change with it?

Comment: @sepupic I do not know if there is already "NoDelay" set to "yes" or not

Comment: Can you ask for more information from the auditor, exactly what they mean?  This is long but interesting thread (old but relevant), you might find useful. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.ms-sqlserver/e1SkBACJZD0

Comment: I think that option is removed in more recent versions but I can't find any documentation except the one you linked to stating "doesn't support this" and older ones stating "you shouldn't touch this" but I can't find any real documentation stating it was removed at some point, so maybe you should ask the auditor as SqlWorldWide suggested